# TCP faster speed using two ports?

Tags: android, windows, image, tcp, lan

i'm transfering some stereo images from a computer to an android mobile and need more speed. Images are in JPEG format. 
Do i get more fps if crop the image by half and send each part over a different TCP port? 
(I can't use UDP)

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it _may_ increase speed (think what browsers do to download from servers). I said "may" because as usual network stuff isn't such straightforward and a test on the road has always last word about performance. In general I would first try to make your _protocol_ lighter to reduce overhead and duplicated information. Also mb/s is only concern or you have also limited computing power?

Comment: If it is on your local wifi lan then maybe it will help. If over internet then you need a very fast connection to begin with to see results as not the processing power of server or client will determine total time but the speed of the connection. In my situation downloading one jpg fully takes all capacity. I made a test app to spawn more and more threads downloading jpg's. One thread is enough i saw. But at friends two were better.

Comment: Right now it's only limited by transfer rate. I do some other stuff with images when received but the bottleneck is here. I will test if using two ports increases speed, but i would like to know why can be faster if using two ports means duplicate TCP control layer and amount of data is the same. Can somebody explain me this? Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget JPEG images can have multiple frames, you'll save some file format overhead. Moreover if you have a single file also a plain old zip compression will help little bit. If you do some processing you may, instead, keep them separated and start processing of first image before 2nd one has finished downloading. In general f.f. for still images aren't optimized for an high speed streaming, compression used for video streams is much better (**it's both interframe and intraframe**).

Comment: Thank you :) I already do what you said, i do image processing in other parallel tread, so transfer and processing are pipelined. But anyway processing is faster than transfer so have to wait. The problem about using some video compression in my case is that is harder to edit frames later. Thank you.